# Can Ma-Ti control humans as well?

Tags: cartoon, powers, captain-planet

Frequently on Captain Planet, Ma-Ti uses the power of heart to control various animals to accomplish certain tasks. Could he use this on humans as well? If so, presumably he could control all the other Planeteers.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not within the show that I've found, but in the third issue of the comic book, ["The Power of Heart"](http://captainplanet.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_Planet_and_the_Planeteers_%28Issue_3%29), it is "... shown that Ma-Ti can use his ring to calm a person down enough to render them unconscious. He manages to render Argos Bleak unconscious by forcing him to look into his own dark heart."

Within the cartoon series, incidentally, he was not shown to have mind control powers with the animals. [He had the ability to communicate with them, and to influence emotions](http://captainplanet.wikia.com/wiki/Ma-Ti#Powers_and_Abilities), but it was always portrayed as him asking them to intervene.

As a possible counter-point, the second part of the "[Two Futures](http://captainplanet.wikia.com/wiki/Two_Futures_Part_II)" episode shows an alternate future Ma-Ti who has become a beggar using his Heart power to convince a businessman to give him some money:

It's ambiguous as to whether he's directly controlling the man, or simply inspiring compassion, and this is an alternate timeline where Wheeler refused the Fire ring (and is set where the other Planeteers have become adults), which may have had effects on their powers.